# Positioning the text inside the cell

Tags: html, css

I have this JSFiddle: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/fvejeLbL/)

```
<table class="findus-main-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img class="static-map" onClick="swap();" id="static-map-id" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom; position: relative;">
            <span style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;">The address I want here</span>
            <!-- the inner table for location and distance and phone number -->
            <table style="text-align:left;" cellspacing="10">
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top">
                        <div>
                            <div>Phone: (613)-123-1234</div>
                            <div>Distance: 0.123km</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><b>Store Hours</b>
                        </div>
                        <div>Mon - Fri: 8am - 2am</div>
                        <div>Sat & Sun: 10am - 12am</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is to position the **address** to the top while the **phone number** and **hours** stays at the bottom. I tried using absolute but it wraps the text of the address which i really dont want.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fvejeLbL/2/  I cannot understand what you mean. See if this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

besides the fact that you shouldn't be using inline styling, is this what you're looking for?

```
<span style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;">
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fvejeLbL/1/)

Comment: thx it works, it was inline because I am current just testing it.

Comment: gotcha, just be sure to check this off as resolved when you can

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `position:absolute` witch should be the last thing anyone should try ,I use `vertical-align:top` 
here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvejeLbL/4/).and here is my css :

```
.address{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:22px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    height: 78px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```